# Title: Google Cloud Run Deployment Error - Container Failed to Start with GCSFuse

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run, gcsfuse

I am following the tutorial on the GCP page to learn how to mount a Google Cloud Storage bucket in [Google Cloud Run using GCSFuse](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse).

I cloned the code from the [official GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples.git) and created the Docker file provided in the tutorial. However, I encounter issues when trying to build and deploy the container both locally and on Google Cloud Run.

```
# Use the official Node.js image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/node
FROM node:20-slim

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    gnupg \
    lsb-release \
    tini && \
    gcsFuseRepo=gcsfuse-`lsb_release -c -s` && \
    echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $gcsFuseRepo main" | \
    tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list && \
    curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | \
    apt-key add - && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gcsfuse && \
    apt-get clean

# Set fallback mount directory
ENV MNT_DIR /mnt/gcs

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY package*.json ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN npm install --only=production

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . ./

# Ensure the script is executable
RUN chmod +x /app/gcsfuse_run.sh

# Use tini to manage zombie processes and signal forwarding
# https://github.com/krallin/tini
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/tini", "--"]

# Pass the wrapper script as arguments to tini
CMD ["/app/gcsfuse_run.sh"]
```

The problem arises when attempting to build the container locally using the command "docker build -t filesystem-app .", where I encounter the "E: Unable to locate package gcsfuse" error. I am using an M1 Apple MacBook Pro, and I suspect that the issue might be related to the different architectures.

However, when I try to deploy the container on Google Cloud Run, it also crashes with the following error:

```
Deployment failed                                                                        
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Revision 'filesystem-app-00013-joh' is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.

Logs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=projet-deploiemne&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/filesystem-app/revision_name/filesystem-app-00013-joh&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22filesystem-app%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22filesystem-app-00013-joh%22 
For more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start
```

It seems that the container fails to start correctly, and I suspect it might be related to the package installation issue I encountered locally.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Clone the code from the provided GitHub repository.
2. Create the Dockerfile as mentioned above.
3. Run "docker build -t filesystem-app ." to build the container locally.
4. Deploy the container on Google Cloud Run.

Expected Outcome:
The container should build successfully locally without any package installation issues, and it should deploy and run correctly on Google Cloud Run without crashing.

Other Information:
I have tried modifying the Dockerfile to include the correct binary for the `arm64` architecture, but the issue persists. I also referred to the gcsfuse documentation and Docker documentation for troubleshooting.

Any insights or solutions to resolve the package installation issue and the container crash on Google Cloud Run would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help and suggestions.

Best regards

Comment: Base on your error mesage [Container failed to start](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start)

"Note: If you build your container image on an ARM based machine, then it might not work as expected when used with Cloud Run. To solve this issue, build your image using Cloud Build."

Comment: The error `container failed to start and listen on the port` tells you the problem. A Cloud Run service must start an HTTP listener and respond to HTTP requests. Your container starts the script file `gcsfuse_run.sh`. What is in that file and does it start an HTTP listener? You mention ARM64. Cloud Run is Intel based at this time. Note: your link is to a huge repository of examples. That is not useful. Your question must be self-contained.

Comment: You can use Cloud Shell to build and test your container "locally". In addition, you have to use the 2nd gen runtime environment on Cloud Run to achieve that. Finally, instead of using tini, you could be able to leverage the side container feature in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki for other's sake:

Base on your error mesage Container failed to start

**Note:** If you build your container image on an ARM based machine, then it might not work as expected when used with Cloud Run. To solve this issue, build your image using Cloud Build.

To check if the container is listening for the requests on the expecting port. The container must listen for approaching request on the port that is defined by the Google Cloud Run and provide the PORT environment variable. [Configure containers](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/services/containers)

As for @John Hanley said:

> The error container failed to start and listen on the port tells you the problem. A Cloud Run service must start an HTTP listener and respond to HTTP requests. Your container starts the script file gcsfuse_run.sh. What is in that file and does it start an HTTP listener? You mention ARM64. Cloud Run is Intel based at this time. Note: your link is to a huge repository of examples. That is not useful. Your question must be self-contained.

Also stated by @Guillaume Blaquiere:

> You can use Cloud Shell to build and test your container "locally". In addition, you have to use the 2nd gen runtime environment on Cloud Run to achieve that. Finally, instead of using tini, you could be able to leverage the side container feature in that case

Additional reference:

- [Building Containers](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/building/containers)
- [Test a Cloud Run service locally](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local)
- [App Engine environments](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments)
- [Container failed to start](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start)